# pushViewController is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and iPhone programming so I apologize if this is a newbie question. I have a simple application that needs to go from one view, to another. The first view is a UIViewController. I set up the xib file in IB (i.e. dragged some buttons onto the window) and hooked up all the buttons (which all work). I then created another xib file and class (also a UIViewController) and hooked them up. When a button is pressed in the first view I want to load the second view. Here's the code that is supposed to be pushing the view:

```
-(IBAction)createAccount:(id)sender{
    CreateAccountViewController*acctView = [[CreateAccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateAccount" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:acctView animated:YES];
    [acctView release];
}
```

But this does nothing. When I put print statements in the createAccount method those are printed (I can click the button any number of times and it never crashes) but the acctView is never pushed. When I print out the value of self.navigationController it returns null. It's even stranger because if I present the acctView modally then it works.

```
-(IBAction)createAccount:(id)sender{
    CreateAccountViewController*acctView = [[CreateAccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateAccount" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:acctView animated:YES];
    [acctView release];
```

}

This works just fine, but I don't want to use the view modally. I'm completely lost here. In the past  couple of hours I've come across a lot of posts saying to do something with a UINavigationController and hook that up to my view, but how do I do that? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have a navigationController? Try NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);

Comment: When I do that it prints that self.navigationController is null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you haven't created a UINavigationController for your app.

Best thing would be starting from scratch with a new Xcode project, taking care of choosing a Navigation Based application. In this way you will get almost everything already set up for you.

If you don't like this approach, you can create programmatically your UINavigationController. [Here](http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/05/23/tutorial-introducing-uinavigationcontroller-part-1/) you find a tutorial for doing that.

If you prefer more straight-to-the-point instructions, here they are:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

     MainPageDialog *overviewViewController = [[MainPageDialog alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainPage" bundle:nil];
     self.navigation = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:overviewViewController] autorelease];
     [overviewViewController release];

     [window addSubview:[navigation view]];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
}
```

whereby `self.navigation` is a `retain`ed property in your appDelegate.

EDIT:

This answer was quite old, therefore an update:

1. If you are using ARC, you should be using a `strong` (vs. `retain`) property and you would not need the `autorelease`;
2. if you target iOS > 4.0 (which is also implied by the above point), you can use the `rootViewController` property in `UIWindow` and say:

   ```
    MainPageDialog *overviewViewController = [[MainPageDialog alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainPage" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:overviewViewController] autorelease];
    [overviewViewController release];

    [window addSubview:[self.window.rootViewController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ```

   without the need for any `navigation` property.

Comment: Best answer to "Why doesn't my pushViewController not work" type questions I've seen in Stack Overflow in years. Succinct and clear. Thanks Sergio.

Comment: This is not correct. You should use self.window.rootViewController = navigation; then release navigation, instead of [window addSubview:[navigation view]];

Comment: @Oliver: thanks for your remark. The answer was quite old so it did not take into account `rootViewController` and the snippet came from an external source, but you are definitely right, especially about the `release`. I added a couple of points to make the answer more up to date (and correct).